# jQuery UI Accordian addressing elements of each panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion I am populating with data from a database. I have all that working well, or at least it appears to be. The issue I am attempting to find a solution for is that each accordion panel contains a form with respective record data populating the form fields.

What I'm wanting to do is to be able to submit each form independently as well as pull the values from the expanded panel to be able to work on that data within my jQuery code.

I've started by trying to use the accordion activate event but cannot seem to figure out how to address elements within that activated panel. I'm fairly certain that this is a rather easy solution. I'm just not sure how to approach it and was hoping someone here has done this before.

Many thanks,

Comment: I would, but I cannot seem to get the accordion to work properly in jsfiddle. Sorry.

Comment: I'll give you a jsfiddle of what it appears I am trying to do.
http://jsfiddle.net/Bf28Q/

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have managed to figure this out on my own. For those of you that have ever had a problem with this, I hope this helps you out.

Here is my working version on jsFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Bf28Q/1/

```
<div id="cust-data-accordian">
  <h3>Joe Schmoe: 1</h3>
  <div id="ac_panel_1">
    <form name="frmDlyUpld" id="frmDlyUpld_1" mehtod="post" action="/functions/update">
      <input type="hidden" name="account_id" id="account_id_1" value="1" />
      First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname_1" value="Joe" /><br />
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname_1" value="Schmoe" /><br />
      <input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="fromSubmit_1" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <h3>Jane Schmoe: 2</h3>
  <div id="ac_panel_2">
    <form name="frmDlyUpld" id="frmDlyUpld_2" mehtod="post" action="/functions/update">
      <input type="hidden" name="account_id" id="account_id_2" value="2" />
      First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname_2" value="Jane" /><br />
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname_2" value="Schmoe" /><br />
      <input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="fromSubmit_2" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

var values = {};
$('#cust-data-accordian').accordion({
  activate: function(i, e) {
    var panel_id = e.newPanel[0].id;
    var acct_id  = panel_id.match(/\d+/);
    var inputs   = $('#frmDlyUpld_' + acct_id + ' :input');
    inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(values);
  }
});
```